# How to get directory name from file path using php

Tags: php, arrays, directory, path

I am trying to get dir name from my file path: Currently below is my output:

```php
Array
(
    [path] => \documentLibrary\work\marketingProcess\BusinessMarketing\Design\Images\02_Product_Images\04_SHORT-RANGE\NINA\01_NINA-B1\source_WEB
)
```

and I want to get second last name which is (01_NINA-B1). What I am trying is:

```
 echo "<pre>".print_r(dirname($results),true)."</pre>"; die;
```

when I add dirname above it displays nothing. What can I try next?

```
     $query = db_select('network_drive','networkd');
     $query
    ->fields('networkd', array('path'))
    ->condition('ndid',$networkdriveid,'=')
    ->orderBy('networkd.ndid');
    $results = $query->execute();
    echo "<pre>".print_r(dirname($results['path']),true)."</pre>"; die;
```

Comment: If `$results` is the array above then you need `dirname($results['path'])`

Comment: it says:      Error: Cannot use object of type DatabaseStatementBase as array in nd_forms_submit() (line 256 of C:\wamp64\www\module_test\modules\nd\nd.module).

Comment: OK, so `$results` is not that array. Can you please update your question with what is actually in `$results`...

Comment: I have posted a whole code please check my edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this drupal? from my research I found out that db_select is a drupal function.

Can you try this one? it will attempt to explode the path string and find the second last element, if none is found it will return "N/A"

```
 $query = db_select('network_drive','networkd');
 $query
->fields('networkd', array('path'))
->condition('ndid',$networkdriveid,'=')
->orderBy('networkd.ndid');
$results = $query->execute();
foreach($results as $result){ 
    $array = explode("\\", $result->path);
    echo isset($array[count($array) - 2]) ? $array[count($array) - 2] : "N/A";
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. and one more thing if i want to go the path which is before 2nd last then i will do -3?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a plain string operation:

1. split the string
2. get the desired element

Maybe like this:

```
$s = '/documentLibrary/work/marketingProcess/BusinessMarketing/Design/Images/02_Product_Images/04_SHORT-RANGE/NINA/01_NINA-B1/source_WEB';

$a = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, dirname($s)); //removes source_WEB and splits the string

echo array_pop($a); //gets the last element '01_NINA-B1'
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vmSGs)